# What single word reflects the feelings/emotions behind “smh”?

Tags: single-word-requests

What single word describes how one feels when another person says something that doesn’t make sense?

I’ve often seen people use shaking my head or scratching my head (“smh”) online. I’m wondering what feelings/emotions pertain to “smh”.

I’m looking for a word that would denote a mild feeling/emotion more akin to when something is ridiculous, absurd, illogical, or laughable.

Example: So and so said something so laughable I feel _____.

Comment: What if it’s something that wouldn’t cause a feeling/emotion as strong as any of those? What word would denote a milder feeling/emotion?

Comment: I have, but I’m not finding feelings and emotions that fit. I’m looking for a feeling or emotion rather than adjectives.

Comment: *Incredulity*, perhaps?

Comment: Incredulity is perfect! And another just came to mind, skeptical. Thank you!

Comment: *Exasperation* is another one that comes to mind

Comment: You could be ***nonplussed***

Comment: Puzzled also works.

Comment: Perplexed, bemused …

Comment: I express it with, “huh?”

Comment: I always thought 'smh' was -shaking- my head, not -scratching- my head. Is it both?

Comment: I think ‘resignation’ suits the scenario. If someone who’s in the habit of making lame jokes makes one, their friends would shake their heads and resign to the fact that they’ll have to bear those jokes. They can’t change what’s happening.

Answer (score 1):

I've always equated *smh* with [**exasperation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exasperation):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : the state of being *exasperated*
>
> : having or showing strong feelings of irritation or annoyance
> // an exasperated sigh

In other words, you're frustrated and can't believe there's a good reason behind something being the way it is. It annoys you.

For example:

> Why do some small items always come in plastic packaging 10 times the size of the item itself, requiring minutes of effort with a sharp object to open? **smh**

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the reason for shaking one's head, but it could be *dismay* at what someone else just said or did, in which case the feeling might be *consternation*.

Comment: This would be improved with dictionary definitions for _dismay_ and _consternation_ (e.g. see Jason's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. First you ask

> What single word describes how one feels when another person says ***something that doesn’t make sense***?

but then you give the example

> So and so said ***something so laughable*** I feel _____.

So first, it is good to make a distinction between ***making no sense (nonsensical)*** and ***laughable*** (*so ludicrous as to be amusing*, [OL](https://www.google.com/search?q=laughable%20meaning&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk007SyoV8CoPTDhD7f3M5J-JXeEB8g%3A1623848477148&source=hp&ei=HfbJYMjdBsaEhbIPk7Su6AM&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYMoELeG4ADXVBVjyJdir5Tn2xJGh9CWw&oq=laughable&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQkQIQRhD5ATIFCAAQkQIyAggAMgIIADICCAAyBAgAEEMyAgguMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIIxAnOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOgkIIxAnEEYQ-QE6BQgAELEDOgQILhBDOgUILhCxAzoLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6BwgAELEDEEM6CAguEMcBEK8BOgoIABCxAxCxAxAKOgcIABCxAxAKOgsILhCxAxDHARCvAToHCAAQhwIQFFCgBljiJWCYO2gBcAB4AIAB8QKIAagNkgEHMC43LjIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=gws-wiz)).

Then you say in the comments you may be looking for a feeling rather than an adjective, and a milder one at that.

I am thinking of ***confusion*** ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/confusion))

> (uncountable) ***a feeling that you do not understand something*** or cannot decide what to do
>
> - She stared at him ***in confusion***.

***Puzzlement*** could be considered slightly stronger, but it is not as strong as ***[perplexity](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/perplexity)*** and ***[bewilderment](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bewilderment)***. It is defined as

> a state of confusion because you do not understand something
>
> - My overall feeling when reading the book was puzzlement. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/puzzlement))

However, these feelings will make sense as answers to the question stated in the title of the OP. So I would re-write your sentence as:

> So and so said something so nonsensical that it left me ***confused/puzzled***.

or with a noun

> So and so said something so nonsensical that it left me with a feeling of ***confusion/puzzlement***.

Addition: There is an even milder way in which you could express this feeling:

> So and so said something so laughable/nonsensical that ***I was left wondering***/ ***it left me wondering***.

Answer (score 1):

I think the two best words for it are unfortunately also two words that are frequently misused to mean something different:

Bemused: puzzled, confused, or bewildered.

Nonplussed: surprised and confused so much that they are unsure how to react.

Comment: +1 for bemused. I had never seen that definition of "nonplussed", though - in the US, it's typically used to mean the exact opposite, indicating that someone is unfazed or has no reaction whatsoever.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Hence my comment about them being frequently misused

Answer (score 0):

I always use *Bewildered* to describe that vague feeling of pleasant confusion. Scratching the head rarely helps but is still the habit.

Answer (score 0):

I might find myself using the term **Baffled** in this scenario. it's fun to say.

> totally bewilder or perplexed.
>
> ```
> "an unexplained occurrence that baffled everyone"
> ```

Comment: totally bewildered or perplexed.